# Visual studio 2012 Workflow 2013 to change file permissions in SharePoint 2013 Document?

Tags: workflow, document-library, permissions, visual-studio-2012

Possible to change file level permission on a document (in document library) with  Visual studio  2012 workflow for SharePoint Online 2013?

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to set permissions using REST API in Workflow.

You can use these methods:

**BreakRoleInheritance​**

BreakRoleInheritance is just not documented and can be used using POST request:

```
https://your_sp_site.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Test')/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true, clearSubscopes=true)
```

where

- *copyRoleAssignments* – if true, this method copies the role assignments of the parent securable object when breaking inheritance; otherwise, this method adds the current user to the permission level that is required to manage the list item.
- *clearSubscopes* – Indicates whether subscopes should be cleared or not.

**AddRoleAssignment**

Instead of the Add there is AddRoleAssignment method that also can be called using POST request (**NOTE: this method works incorrectly in RTM release of SharePoint 2013!!!! It checks user within current item and if user is  not found (usually as we've just broken inheritance) throws an exception.  In SharePoint Online and March CU it works as expected**):

```
https://your_sp_site.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Test')/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=20,roleDefId=1073741828)
```

where

- *principalid*  - id of user or group within current site collection. You can get a list of users by executing using GET: `https://your_sp_site.sharepoint.com/_api/web/siteusers`
- *roleDefId* -  internal id of Role Definition (Read, Contribute, Full Control and so on). You can get a list of available role definitions using GET: `https://your_sp_site.sharepoint.com/_api/web/roledefinitions​`

Also you can find workflow activities to work with permissions on [codeplex](https://sp2013workflowactivities.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Please avoid link only answers as shown in our [help section](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): "**Provide context for links** Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."